# Powershell сравнение хэш таблиц

Tags: xml, powershell

Имеются 2 хэш таблицы **$table1** и **$table2**.
Данные сформированы из xml файла.

**$table1**

```
Name   Value                                                                                                                                              
----   -----                                                                                                                                 
user1    id1                                                                                                                 
user2    id2
user3    id3  
user4    id4  
user5    id5
```

**$table2**

```
Name   Value                                                                                                                                                 
----   -----                                                                                                                                                 
id5    ruk_id3                                                                                                                  
id2    ruk_id2                                                                                                                  
id1    ruk_id5  
id4    ruk_id1  
id3    ruk_id4
```

Необходимо сравнить значения `$table1.Values` и `$table2.Keys` чтобы в итого получилось:

**$table3**

```
Name   Value                                                                                                                                                 
----   -----                                                                                                                                                 
user1    ruk_id5                                                                                                                 
user2    ruk_id2  
user3    ruk_id4  
user4    ruk_id1  
user5    ruk_id3
```

Comment: пожалуйста, не могли бы предоставить необходимые данные, чтобы легко можно было воспроизвести? нажмите править и добавьте xml и ваш код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($key in $table1.keys)
{
    $id = $table1[$key]
    $val = $table2[$id]
    echo($key + ' ' + $val)
}
```

Comment: Александр, спасибо! Именно то что надо было :)